# Why is rails not inserting data during create, only nil? (New scaffold)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, commit, null, scaffold

I had an annoying problem with a freshly generated scaffold. Everything would run nicely, but while I could enter data, everytime I tried to save he would commit nil successfully. For all fields.

Looks like this:

```
Started POST "/spraches" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-08-26 23:34:03 +0200
Processing by SprachesController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"nMf1+rBegI9BKoSAekzq8iLPQPAHpiiPk2DlmhEQxsQ=", "sprache"=>{"name"=>"23", "level"=>"23", "zertifikat"=>"124", "zertifikat_anders"=>"213", "zertifikat_note"=>"f23"}, "commit"=>"Create Sprache"}
  [1m[36m (1.0ms)[0m  [1mBEGIN[0m
  [1m[35mSQL (29.0ms)[0m  INSERT INTO "spraches" ("created_at", "level", "name", "updated_at", "zertifikat", "zertifikat_anders", "zertifikat_note") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7) RETURNING "id"  [["created_at", Sun, 26 Aug 2012 21:34:03 UTC +00:00], ["level", nil], ["name", nil], ["updated_at", Sun, 26 Aug 2012 21:34:03 UTC +00:00], ["zertifikat", nil], ["zertifikat_anders", nil], ["zertifikat_note", nil]]
  [1m[36m (1.0ms)[0m  [1mCOMMIT[0m
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/spraches/1
Completed 302 Found in 35ms (ActiveRecord: 31.0ms)
```

The reason become obivous to me after looking at the code in detail: I named my table in German (Sprache -> Language) and Rails tried to set it to plural. However, the controller only had it in the singular form.

```
@sprach = Sprache.new(params[:sprach])
```

I addded an "e" in the params to match the incoming code. Works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason become obivous to me after looking at the code in detail: I named my table in `German (Sprache -> Language)` and Rails tried to set it to `plural`. However, the controller only had it in the `singular` form.

```
@sprach = Sprache.new(params[:sprach])
```

I addded an `"e"` in the params to match the incoming code. Works.